# C++ Multithreading on Unix

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have two related questions:

1. Are there any good books for multithreading in C++, especially now that C++11 contains multithreading in the standard library?
2. I have the Wrox Programming on Unix book (1000 pages fat red one) and within it, it uses the Unix Thread class.

   - How does this code relate to boost and the C++11 multithreading libraries?
   - Is it better/worse/just specific to Unix etc?
   - Is the performance the same?

Comment: The only book I know that covers C++11's threading/concurrency mechanisms so far is [C++ Concurrency in Action](http://www.manning.com/williams/), which was just released a month ago.

Comment: What is "the Unix Thread class" ?

Answer (score 7):

That's quite a question!

Threading is an OS task and traditionally people used pthreads on Unix and Windows Gui threads on Windows.
Boost::threads basically wraps these operating system services. How the compiler and OS maker implement c++11 threads is upto them, but generally you would not expect a huge performance difference between any of them.

If performance really matters then you probably need to get much finer grained than any of the  general thread libraries and look at [openMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openmp), [Intel TBB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TBB) or [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL).

Comment: +1 Good answer, I would just add some links to openMP, Intel TBB and OpenCL. You are all over the place @Martin.